# Fantasy book with battle between owls and crows

Tags: story-identification, novel, books

I have a difficult one here. I am trying to track down a fantasy book for my Dad, but the problem is that his memory is not quite there these days. He remembers really enjoying the book but frustratingly only a few details about it, as follows:

- It seems it was a classic good mustering forces to battle a monstrous
  evil.
- Near the beginning there was battle between Owls and Crows (or
  possibly ravens). The owls were the good guys and somewhat
  outnumbered by the crows.
- The good guys encompassed a number of groups of people/cultures
  including a small sect of 'ninja'-like warriors.
- He last read it about 30 years ago.
- He described a paperback book binding that could well indicate "Unicorn" as the publisher, i.e. it was mainly black with the front cover encompassing some sort of framed art work with what might have been a unicorn at the top
  of the frame.

I know this is not much to go on at all (sorry), but if a title could be found, it would certainly make my dad happy.

Comment: Could you run https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-WBICYHRtppA/WN-57EstyVI/AAAAAAAAzqE/qeYS_rJeOJcPinVSXwCn3On5uhbqsWh1gCLcB/s1600/Unwin-23266a%2BRyman%2BWarrior%2BWho%2BCarried%2BLife.jpg by him and see if the logo matches his memory?

Comment: If so, it would probably be something from "Unicorn / Unwin Paperbacks". http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pubs_not_in_series.cgi?28180

Comment: Another possibility is the Robin Hobbs Farseer Trilogy - That has the Owls and Ravens as clans, but I don't remember if they battle or not.

Comment: What about *The Dark Is Rising* series, by Susan Cooper? Wasn’t there something about birds in there?

Comment: @JohnP there aren't any Owls, crows or ravens in the Farseer books. There are 16 books in that series and there are no clans or ninjas in any of them.

Comment: @Jontia - YOu are correct. I meant the Tawny Man series, same author. Got them mixed up.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your ideas. FuzzyBoots - My dad thinks the format of the front cover picture you provided is exactly as he remembers it, and the list of Unwin/Unicorn publications is an excellent start. Many thanks.

Comment: I'm requesting a copy of *The Badger of Ghissi* from my library ILL. A Google Books search doesn't bring up any smoking guns, but it is a fantasy epic compared to The Lord of the Rings, so it seems like the right sort of book.

Comment: And *The Badger of Ghissi* seems to be a bad match. The first few chapters are basically about the political and religious intrigue that happens when a serving maid who is not a maiden takes on the literal mantle of her bishop patron after he dies in a bandit attack.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Thanks very much for trying that. I have had no luck as yet. Given the vague description i provided, It was all a bit of a long shot i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [The Tales Of Panchatantra](http://www.talesofpanchatantra.com/) - The War of Crows and Owls? I'm most likely wrong due to the description of the front cover and the whole ninja addition. I'm not sure how old this book is or if the book your father read was more of a children's book or so fourth.

Comment: Could you [edit] to explain how this matches the OP's description?